# How to create a toc in an HTML file using an .Rmd file and Rstudio?

Tags: html, rstudio, r-markdown, tableofcontents

How can I make an html like this: http://rpubs.com/wch/17105 using Rstudio in an .Rmd file? I read the page http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ and put this code at the beginning of my .Rmd file:

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: united
---
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

The table of contents automatically picks up headers from the main document to the specified depth of the YAML key `toc_depth`; the default is `toc_depth: 3`<sup>[1](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#table-of-contents)</sup>. See [this documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#headers) for the different possible types of headers. Here's example syntax of the so-called "Atx-style" headers:

```
# Header 1

## Header 2

### Header 3
```